# How to provide Custom name for generated DataBinding Class?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-jetpack

The *tasks_frag.xml* is a layout file with DataBinding, and I hope to import the generated class to *TasksFragment.kt*, you can see Image A.

I know that Android generates the class name *TasksFragBinding* based *tasks_frag* by a rule automatically, but the rule is hard to remember.

Is there a simple way to import the generated DataBinding class in Android Studio?

**tasks_frag.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
    </data>
    ...

</layout>
```

**TasksFragment.kt**

```
import com.example.android.architecture.blueprints.todoapp.databinding.TasksFragBinding
class TasksFragment : Fragment() {
  ...
}
```

**Image A**
[image]

Comment: Are you manually importing the class? Typically `Alt+Enter` will import the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If for some reasons you are disappointed by the name of the generated binding class, you are allowed to name them as you want.

As per the docs,

> Binding classes may be renamed or placed in different packages by
>   adjusting the class attribute of the data element.

Just provide the class name you want in the `<data class="SomeClass">` tag.

In your case,

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data class="MyClassName">
    </data>
    ...

</layout>
```

And then you are assured that generated binding class will be named as `MyClassName` which you can easily import.

Comment: Thanks! But It seems there are some problems with your way

Comment: There are some problems with another generated automatically class MyClassNameImpl, it displays `An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: After the above steps completed, you can try with `Invalidate Caches/Restart` option. This will clear any cached generated files and will regenerate them.